# Serializing 2 tables using Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I need to Serialize 2 table to one `JSON` object, i have worked with DRF and know how to go about serializing a single model to `JSON`. These are the 2 models -

```
class FooOne(models.Model):
      field_a = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
      field_b = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
      field_c = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

class FooTwo(models.Model):
      field_fk = models.ForeignKey(FooOne)
      field_d = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
      field_e = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

How do i go about achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do it using nested representation.

```
class FooOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = FooOne
        fields = (field_a, field_b, field_c)

class FooTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    field_fk = FooOneSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = FooTwo
        fields = (field_fk, field_d, field_e)
```

If you want just return everything in a non-nested representation

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
data = FooOneSerializer(instance=foo_one_instance).data
data.update(FooTwoSerializer(instance=foo_two_instance).data)
json_data = JSONRenderer().render(data)
```

Comment: Right so i get that, thing is, since FooOne model is a foreign key to FooTwo.  My JSON must be a nested one where FooTwo is nested to which ever field  in FooOne its fk-ed to.

Comment: works, not the exact result i was looking for. But i can work from here on out. Thank you.

Comment: could you please leave the first answer you gave in the comment?